# Pass function result into property

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic2

I am building up an Ionic 2 app using Google Maps SDK.

I want a user to be able to add markers on the map.

My code which adds markers by button click looks like this:

```
addMarker(){

    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: this.map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position: this.map.getCenter()
    });

    let content = "<h4>Information!</h4>";          

    this.addInfoWindow(marker, content);

}
```

**position: this.map.getCenter()** makes the Pin always added in the centre of the map.

The following function should return latitude / longitude of the clicked place on the map:

```
addNewPlace(){
  let newPlace = new google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'click', (event) => latLng);
}
```

and  I want the result from above (**latLng**) to be inserted into the **addMarker** function:

```
addMarker(){

    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: this.map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position: newPlace
    });

    let content = "<h4>Information!</h4>";          

    this.addInfoWindow(marker, content);

}
```

How can I do that? 
For now browser simply ignores my addNewPlace function (nothing happens, no errors in console).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a click listener for map in your initialization function where you create a map. There is no need to create addNewPlace() function. Please also note that there is no constructor for google.maps.event.addListener(). No need for new operator.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#event

Callback function for click event returns an MouseEvent object

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MouseEvent

So you can create a function

```
addMarker(newPlace) {

    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: this.map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position: newPlace
    });

    let content = "<h4>Information!</h4>";          

    this.addInfoWindow(marker, content);
}
```

In your initialization function after map creation add

```
google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'click', (event) => {
    addMarker(event.latLng);
});
```